# Multivariable Calculus: surfaces and direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I was trying out this problem that I happened to come across which states the following

"You are standing on a surface given by the equation $z$=$\ 4x^{2}-2xy-y^{2}$ at the point (1,2,-4). In which direction is the fastest way up and down?"

My thinking was to find the gradient vector of the surface and plug in the given point and find the unit vector of the gradient. Am I in the right track?

Comment: Just don't forget up *and* down!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Just remember that the gradient points in the direction of maximum *increase*. To get the direction of maximum *decrease*, take the negative. I presume the question wants both of them.